# Getting 404 and 500 errors - XmlHttp

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I'm running code like this - for a while:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
// Wait to get query result
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)  // Request finished
{
    // Do something with the responsexmlhttp.response;
}
}
var request = "something.php?operation=bla-bla";

xmlhttp.open("GET", request, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

It was working perfectly until some weeks ago. Error code 500 or 404 is catched by the browser (or by the code).
However - running the request directly in the address bar never return error.

I tried to reinstall google-chrome. Didn't help.
I run the code in firefox - got the some problem.

Any idea where to dig?

Thanks, Yaakov.

Comment: Those error codes are from your *server*. That's where you need to look at logs etc. to see what's wrong.

Comment: Make sure `something.php` is in the exact same path as the page using this javascript. Otherwise, use absolute paths.

Comment: Maybe it isn't reaching the URL `something.php?operation=bla-bla`...

Comment: you can't fix a 500 with javascript. the 404 means you have the wrong url. you'd need to post the php in order for anyone to hazard a guess about what caused it.

Comment: Dears,
The url is right. Alwats works when accessing it from the address bar.
How do I debug the server?
It's cpanel apache running php 5.4.

Comment: OK!

The problem seems to be in the server. I had limit of 128M in the php.ini file.
I use wordpress - takes alone 50M! So script calling another cause process creation error.